# Sonicwall tz400 - is the proposed architecture for a site to site VPN possible?

Tags: sonicwall

I'm new to SonicWALL and Site to Site VPN Configurations.

We have a sonic wall tz400 and have our local workstations configured to receive public IPs in the 167.x.x.x/24 range. The question is if the SonicWall can be configured to do a site to site VPN attached to the same network as the workstations and route traffic from these workstations to the destination network.

The destination private network is in the 10.x.x.x/24 range with a public IP for their VPN concentrator of 209.x.x.x/24.

The way that I conceptually see this working is to  use the WAN X1 port on the SonicWALL, initially configure the workstations  with static routes for the destination 10. network to use the Static 167.x.x.x address on the SonicWALL WAN port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SonicWALL to create [IPsec Site to Site Tunnel](https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw5857).

But if you want to provide tunnel to another PC on the same WAN subnet it will be difficult (different subnet destination)